# How to enable runtime scaffolding in EF Core

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget, npgsql

Creating dynamic ASP.NET MVC EF Core application with Npgsql EF Core provider.

I tried to implement runtime scaffolding as described in

https://medium.com/@zaikinsr/roslyn-ef-core-runtime-dbcontext-constructing-285a9d67bc87

In project .config file

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

is changed to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.2"/>
```

After that yellow warning icons appear in Visual Studio Solution Explore Dependecies tree:

[image]

Build and package manager windows do not contain any warnings.
How to find warning message related to this icon ?
How to fix this ?

Which is proper way to use scaffold in runtime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your steps on my side with `Asp Net Core 3.1 MVC` project, I did not face the same situation with the yellow icon.

Please try the following steps:

1. [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first or just delete all files under `C:\Users\Administrator\.nuget\packages`.

   **Then**, close VS, , delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of your project.

   After that, restart your project to test again.
2. add `dotnet restore` under Project **Properties**-->**Build Events**--> **Pre-build event command line**, then build your project to test again.
3. create a new **Asp Net Core** project to test again.